# Disable some ToggleButtons in a GridPane based on which ToggleButton is selected

Tags: java, javafx

I have a GridPane (in JavaFX) filled with ToggleButtons like this:

```
int grootte = 4;

ToggleButton letter[][] = new ToggleButton[grootte][grootte];

for (int i = 0; i < grootte; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < grootte; j++){
            final int x = i;
            final int y = j;
            letter[x][y] = new ToggleButton(letters.get("a"));
            letter[x][y].setId(x + "" + y);
            letter[x][y].setMinSize(50, 50);
            gp.add(letter[x][j], i, j);
            letter[x][y].setOnAction(e -> btnPress(letter[x][y]));
        }
    }
}
```

The btnPress method is this:

```
public void btnPress(ToggleButton letter){
    System.out.println(letter.getId());
    if (letter.isSelected()){
        woord.appendText(letter.getText());
    }
}
```

So, I have a GridPane filled with 4x4 ToggleButtons that display "a".

What I want to do is make it so that when I select a ToggleButton, I can only select a next ToggleButton if it is right next to it horizontally, vertically and diagonally.

I'm already getting the position of the button by assigning an ID to each button, but im not sure on where to go from here.

Comment: Add a listener to the button and depending on what's pressed do a certain action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
letter[x][y].selectedProperty().addListener((obs, wasSelected, isNowSelected) -> {
    if (isNowSelected) {
        updateToggleButtonStates(letter, x, y);
    } else {
        // not sure if you want to do something when buttons are deselected?
    }
});
```

with

```
private void updateToggleButtonStates(ToggleButton[][] buttons, int x, int y) {
    for (int i = 0 ; i < buttons.length ; i++) {
        for (int j = 0 ; j < buttons[i].length ; j++) {
            buttons[i][j].setDisable(Math.abs(i-x) > 1 || Math.abs(j-y) > 1);
        }
    }
}
```

(So buttons that are not in an adjacent column or the same column, or are not in an adjacent row or the same row, will be disabled; remaining buttons will be enabled.)

Comment: This is exactly what I need! Thank you very much!